# Render() state element is initially empty until api call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, redux, react-component

I have a class component which should display some list values after an API call, in my render function I call a function to populate some other state list (with specific object properties from the fetched list), the problem is that in the render call, the state values are initially empty and as such the component I return is also just empty.

I've tried using componentDidUpdate() but I dont have much of an idea on how to go about using it, it usually gives me an infinite loop.

Here is my relevant code:

```js
class AdminSales extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      items: [],
      data: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData() {
    fetch("/api/items")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((items) => this.setState({ items: items }));
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevState) {
    if (JSON.stringify(prevState.items) == JSON.stringify(this.state.items)) {
      // Do nothing 
    } else {
      // This gives infinite loop ...
      // this.fetchData();
    }

  }

  populateData() {
    this.state.items.forEach(function (item) {
      this.state.data.push({
        name: item.name,
        value: item.quantity,
      });
    }, this);
  }

  render() {
    // Output shown line: 65
    console.log(this.state);
    this.populateData();
    const { data } = this.state;
    return ( ... );
  }
}

export default AdminSales;
```

[image]

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Other than the obvious state mutations and side-effects in `render`, what is the point of duplicating the `items` state into the `data` state? Seems pretty pointless. React component state should be the minimum amount of data it takes to represent your data, you should avoid duplication. Unless you define your state with non-empty arrays they will ***always*** be empty on the initial render cycle. If this is a problem then apply some conditional rendering until the fetched data is populated in state.

Comment: Yeah that was pretty silly of me, I was trying to format it but then realized I could just do that within the fetch request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all there are multiple issues in your code

- Updating/Mutating state in `render`
- Instead of updating the state using `setState`, updating the state inplace in `populateData` method

Also, as @Drew mentioned we don't have to duplicate `items` into `data` instead we can store only the required info in the state once after getting the response from the API.

In the meantime while waiting for the response if you want to show a loading info you can do that as well.

Below is the example covering all those points mentioned above.

```js
const mockAPI = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => {
    resolve([{id:1, name: "ABC", quantity: 1}, {id: 2, name: "DEF", quantity: 5}, {id: 3, name: "XYZ", quantity: 9}])
  }, 500));
}

class AdminSales extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      items: [],
      loading: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData = () => {
    mockAPI()
      .then((res) => {
        this.populateData(res);
      });
  }

  populateData = (data) => {
    this.setState({ 
      items: data.map(({name, quantity}) => ({
        name,
        value: quantity
      })),
      loading: false
    })
  }

  render() {
    //console.log(this.state);
    const { items, loading } = this.state;
    return loading ? <p>Loading...</p> : 
    items.map(item => (
      <div>{item.name}: {item.value}</div>
    ));
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<AdminSales />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

> **Note:** For simplicity I've mocked the backend API with simple `setTimeout`.

Comment: Yesss, it works now! Thanks alot for the detailed answer! :)

Comment: I'm happy to have helped you :-)